# List Okta usernames assigned to app via postman

Tags: postman, okta, okta-api

Is there a way, via Postman, to list the usernames assigned to an application. I am not looking for the Okta username, rather the username being passed to the SP. If yes, is there a way to limit the response to only that value as opposed to all values that get returned when you list a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

What you want to get is what is sent in the SAML Assertion right ?

I was able to get it using something like this:

```
oktaorg../api/v1/apps/0oa1775fsuhaO5wKD1d8/users/00uy74c0h7NGTLBSXQOC
```

Here is what it returned

```
{ "id": "00uy74c0h7NGTLBSXQOC",
"externalId": null,
 "created": "2017-03-10T19:17:05.000Z",
"lastUpdated": "2017-03-10T19:17:05.000Z",
"scope": "GROUP",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"statusChanged": "2017-03-10T19:17:05.000Z",
"passwordChanged": null,
"syncState": "DISABLED",
"lastSync": null,
"credentials": {
  "userName": "oktaadmin2@okta.com" /*this is what you want I think */
},
"profile": {},
"_links": {
  "app": {
    "href": "https://companyx.okta.com/api/v1/apps/0oa1775fsuhaO5wKD1d8"
},
"group": {
  "name": "Everyone",
  "href": "https://companyx.okta.com/api/v1/groups/00gy74c0gzOSVLSLVYIG"
},
"user": {
  "href": "https://companyx.okta.com/api/v1/users/00uy74c0h7NGTLBSXQOC"
}
  }
}
```